# Request callback issue with infinite crawler

Tags: scrapy

I am writing a Scrapy spider whose purpose is to make requests to a remote server in order to hydrate the cache. It's an infinite crawler because I need to make requests after regular intervals. I created initial spider which generates request and hit the server, it worked fine but now when I am making it running infinitely, I am not getting responses. I even tried to debug in the `process_response` middleware but couldn't get my spider till there. Here is a sketch of code which I am implementing

```
 def generate_requests(self, payloads):
        for payload in payloads:
            if payload:
                print(f'making request with payload {payload}')
                yield Request(url=Config.HOTEL_CACHE_AVAILABILITIES_URL, method='POST', headers=Config.HEADERS,
                              callback=self.parse, body=json.dumps(payload), dont_filter=True, priority=1)

 def start_requests(self):
        crawler_config = CrawlerConfig()
        while True:
            if not self.city_scheduler:
                for location in crawler_config.locations:
                    city_name = location.city_name
                    ttl = crawler_config.get_city_ttl(city_name)
                    payloads = crawler_config.payloads.generate_payloads(location)
                    self.city_scheduler[location.city_name] = (datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=ttl)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

                    yield from self.generate_requests(payloads)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like scrapy has some odd behavior with while loop in start_requests. you can check similar enhancement on [scrapy repo here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3259). 
Moving while loop logic in your parse method will solve this issue.